# How to compute tensor product between two functions

Tags: tensor-products, tensor-rank

Let $f$ and $g$ are two functions defined on $[0,1]$ and taking values in a Hilbert space $H$.
 Then how to define and compute the tensor product between $f$ and $g$, namely $f\otimes g$?

I know how to compute the tensor product between vectors and matrices (same as  the kronecker product). But unable to do the same for functions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$f \otimes g$ is the function $[0,1]^2 \to \mathbb C$ given by $(f \otimes g)(x,y) = f(x) g(y) $.

Comment: Remember that $f$ and $g$ take values in a Hilbert space. What exactly is the product $f(x)g(y)$ you are referring to? The inner product? Or the tensor product? I'm pretty sure that the tensor product of functions is given by $(f \otimes g)(x,y) = f(x) \otimes g(y)$

Comment: Yes, I missed that the functions took values in a Hilbert space.  I agree with your answer.